# Real android project in Github

Tags: android, github, open-source

I am looking for applications to see how they are built, features etc...
For example the app [smspopup](https://github.com/everythingandroid/android-smspopup) seems very nice for studying.

Does anybody know any other worthwhile open source projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always suggest the [iosched](https://github.com/google/iosched) project as a pretty full example, I would start downloading the project and learning everything from the source code. As it is developed by Google developers, it fulfills all Android code patterns and also has the latest Android Material design.

If you want more Android projects, there are several pages for it in [github](https://github.com/pcqpcq/open-source-android-apps).